# Microsoft Access 2016 Query Returns 1/1/1800 for Null Dates in Linked Table

Tags: sql-server, azure, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have a Access 2016 database with linked tables. They're linked to an Azure SQL database. When I include the table in an Access query, null dates appear as 1/1/1800. If I just open the table in Access null dates are blank. Here is the query:

```
SELECT dbo_WTSI_Jobs.Id, dbo_WTSI_Jobs.JobNo, dbo_WTSI_Jobs.CreatedDate, dbo_WTSI_Jobs.CompletedDate
FROM dbo_WTSI_Jobs
WHERE (((dbo_WTSI_Jobs.CreatedDate)>#1/1/2017#));
```

This query returns dbo_WTSI_Jobs.CompletedDate as 1/1/1800 when it is null. If I omit the WHERE clause, null dbo_WTSI_Jobs.CompletedDate values are empty strings.

How do I prevent the query from returning 1/1/1800 ?

Comment: It sounds like they aren't actually `NULL` values, they are empty strings. When trying to convert an empty string to a date, you'll get the minimum possible date. You could try something like `SWITCH(dbo_WTSI_Jobs.CompletedDate = "", NULL)`. Something like that would return an actual `NULL` value for that column.

Comment: You're right, they're not null. This expression returns false: Expr1: IsNull([dbo_WTSI_Jobs].[CompletedDate]). I am not familiar with the SWITCH function, but the following solved my problem: CompletedDateCalc: IIf([CompletedDate]=#1/1/1800#,"",[CompletedDate]). By the way, the data type is datetime. Thanks all for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Change the data type of the field to datetime.

Comment: Wouldn't the problem still exist? It will still convert the empty strings to `1/1/1800`, only stored in the DB this time.

Comment: If the data type is _DateTime_, you cannot receive the date 1800-01-01 as a default or "null" date; in Access, that is 1899-12-30.

Answer (score 0):

The following solved my problem: CompletedDateCalc: IIf([CompletedDate]=#1/1/1800#,"",[CompletedDate]).